# Ubuntu GCC version error with correct GCC version

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++

I'm getting this error during an installation:

```
Using HPHP_HOME == /home/dev/hhvm
-- CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH was missing, proceeding anyway
CMake Warning at CMake/HPHPSetup.cmake:47 (message):
  chrpath not found, rpath will not be stripped from installed binaries
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  hphp/CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)


CMake Error at CMake/HPHPCompiler.cmake:11 (message):
  Need at least GCC 4.7
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/HPHPSetup.cmake:61 (include)
  hphp/CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

When I run `gcc --version` the output is: `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.7.3`

Comment: Why you need hhvm? Have you did everything possible to profile and improve your existing PHP code? Or do you just want to make bad written PHP code performing better?

Comment: haha, I want to experiment with it

Comment: You see I'm not a friend of that stuff too much ;)

Comment: However, what if you try `cc --version` ? same results?

Comment: Aha, but still, it's a strange GCC error... (don't you think?)

Comment: Yeah, I think that too. What gives you `cc --version` ? (Usually cc will be just a link to gcc, but lets have a look)

Comment: `cc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.7.3`

Comment: can you post a link to the sources? I may try on my own

Comment: Did you run `configure_ubuntu_12.04.sh` before compiling? Seems that this is required for ubuntu12.04

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-Ubuntu-12.04

Comment: Hmm I guess not, just checking.
BTW, why are you no fan of HHVM?

Comment: If PHP code is well written and performance optimized and then there are still performance issues with an application, then I'm a fan of it. However mostly developers don't think about optimizing their own code but making things far too complicated using optimization tools like hhvm

Comment: hek2mgl I think @VonC means me... Well, I assumed it was a non-issue really...

Comment: @hek2mgl yeah fair enough, I have this strange thing that I like every millisecond I can win :-P

Comment: Can I see the php code?

Comment: Yes, get your copy here (haha) http://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Comment: I'm responsible for several magento installations. ;) OK, why don't you say that?.. Being responsible for a 3rd party application, where you can't change the code is a thumb up for optimization tools.